# Как скачать файл через Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Использую `Vue.js`. Чтобы получить файл, обращаюсь к серверу. На сервере следующий код:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
readfile('динамическая_генерация_файла');
```

Хочу, чтобы после получения ответа от сервера началось скачивание файла в браузере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Началось скачивание файла":

```js
var data = new Blob(["\ufeff", ['File content here']],{type:'plain/text'});
var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
window.location.href=file;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="download.php" download="downloaded.pdf">download<a>
```

Не то что вы ищете?