# отдать файл на скачивание браузеру через ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Имеется скрипт:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="oferta_' . date("d.m.Y") . '.pdf"');
echo $list;
```

и `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/ajax/ajax_online_status_contract.php",
  data: { 
    nms:nms,
  },
  success: function (data) {},
  error: function (result) { alert("Error");}
})
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при получении ответа браузер выдавал окно скачивания этого файла. Прямой ссылки на файл нет. Файл формируется

Comment: здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709570/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-ajax?rq=1 смотрели?

Comment: думаю подходит , но может еще подскажете как сформировать заголок под pfp строка вида `var file_1 = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });` что-то не подходит

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в PHP хэдер `header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');`

Comment: @Kosmos к сожалению не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте этот пример - https://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/pen/RKxJNo . Только не забудьте поменять параметр `url` на свой